# OData Core Action ArgumetntNullException

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I have defined an action with a nullable Guid parmeter as follows:

```
   var searchLocationAction = builder.EntityType<SearchDummyDTO>().Collection.Action("GetLocation").Returns<SearchResultDTO>();
    searchLocationAction.Parameter<string>("searchPhrase");
    searchLocationAction.Parameter<Guid?>("areaId");
```

Controller method looks like

```
 [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetLocation(ODataActionParameters parameters)
```

In the scenario that an API consumer makes a request with a wrong body:

```
{"searchPhrase":"","areaId":""}
```

An exception will be raised without any feedback to the user. Also in development mode we will get an argument null exception:

```
    <h1>An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.</h1>
    <div class="titleerror">ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.<br />
Parameter name: source</div>
        <p class="location">System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList&lt;TSource&gt;(IEnumerable&lt;TSource&gt; source)</p>
```

I am trying to find a solution to at least let the consumer know that there is a problem with the request body.

What i tried was creating a custom middleware to catch ODataException but this not being raised as an odata exception this is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging through the code i realized that in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLocation(ODataActionParameters parameters)
```

The ODataActionParameters were null, this was because of ModelState error, and code down the line was not expecting null value.

Even tough we have a model state check in place this was bypassed at a point and not handled properly.

The solution is to get error from ModelState and return BadRequest.